# Как интерполировать прогноз?

Tags: математика, javascript

Долгоиграющая задача выполняется шагами: череда ajax вызовов. На шаг выходит секунд 12–18. Пользователю хочется показывать что-то часто обновляемое, предсказуемое.

[Сделал](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/r81zmtn5/) линейно: предполагаю, что `progress = f(time)` это просто `k * time`. (На фиддл имитация со случайным временем выполнения +- 4 секунды) При поступлении следующего ответа, этот k корректируется исходя из последней полученной точки.

Но, похоже, это неправильно: если реальный шаг внезапно тормозит, по сравнению с предыдущими, мой прогресс откатывается назад, когда приходят наконец реальные данные.

**Как можно относительно реалистично угадывать прогресс, опираясь на дискретные шаги?**

Comment: Вы когда нибудь видели, как internet explorer качает файл и пишет время до окончания? когда там не то что часы, там бывали и года.

Comment: @KoVadim к счастью, давно не видел : ) В моей задаче будем считать мир идеальным, а отклонения в разумных пределах.

Comment: я бы делал так - брал последние 5-6 значений, усреднял их и использовал для расчета оставшегося времени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответа не нашлось, [придумал такое решение](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/3dL4rjo1/6/): показывать юзеру прогресс как ф-ю от времени, которая асимптоматически стремится к очередному шагу прогресса, никогда его не достигая. Когда шаг в реале достигается, устанавливается следующая цель, а стартовая точка - показанный на сейчас %. Для наблюдателя это выглядит как ускорение/замедление постоянно растущего прогресс-бара.

Математика: ф-ия вида `y = A + AB/(-x^2-B)`, которая стартует из заданной точки (a,b) и в ожидаемое время *t* достигает значения `k * A`, где k чуть меньше 1, а дальше приближается, но никогда не достигает A:

[image: ф-я]